# Radical of a polynomial values

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

It has been observed by Langevin and Elkies that the following holds:

Assume that the $ABC$- conjecture is true. Suppose that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has no repeated roots. Fix $\varepsilon >0.$ Then
$$\prod_{p\vert f(m)} p\gg|m|^{\deg f-1-\varepsilon}.$$

Since there are several unconditional bounds for radical of $c$ where $a+b=c,$ $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, I was wondering if anything is known unconditionally for $\text{rad}(f(n)).$